# I want to fetch logs from google cloud, with all the attributes, in the exact JSON format using python

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am using Client Library.

```
for entry in logging_client.list_entries(order_by=DESCENDING, filter_=FILTER, page_size=1):

    timestamp = entry.timestamp.isoformat()
    print('****{}'.format(entry.payload_pb))
    print (entry.payload_pb)
    print('* {}: {}: {}'.format(timestamp, entry.logger.name, entry.insert_id))
```

But `payload_pb`, has just two attributes: `value` and `type_url`. 
And otherwise I can fetch just a few values like `timestamp`, `logName`, `insertId`.

I want to fetch the values inside '`protopayload`'. Please suggest a way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way for client library. However, I used Python [API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list),

`loglist = bq.entries().list(body=request_body).execute()`

Here, `bq` is the response from discovery.build and `loglist` provides the response in JSON format, with combinations of `dicts` and `lists`. We have to dig in them, to get the exact key value pair.

I hope this just helps somebody who needs to get job done somehow, like me!

Comment: Can you post complete example , it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can make the API return a `dict` (JSON) payload by setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC` to a non-empty string, e.g. `GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC=true`.

This will populate `payload` instead of `payload_pb`.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the hints provided, I could not make it work with the API.

Instead you could export the logs to a sink like BigQuery and query using SQL from there. See here how-to https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2

Since there is no code out there - sample or example - on how to read the specific protobuf payload from GCP services, it may not be ready for prime time or not meant to be used that way. AAMOF the only documentation is - as of today - only for writing & reading custom logs.

Here the issue I had raised if you want to follow up on: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/5313

Comment: Thanks. Can you though, upvote the question. Need some reputations.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of the proto payload is a serialized protocol buffer message. You'll need to deserialize it to read the fields within the message.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

The proto payload is an [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) message, and the type of the value is  indicated by `type_url`

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any

Once you have the proto message, you can convert it to JSON with [json_format.MessageToJson](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py).

It would also be possible to handle the `Any` message directly with `MessageToJson` as long as the descriptor of the proto message is known. This can be done by updating the proto [symbol database](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/symbol_database.py) via `RegisterMessage'.

Comment: OP asked specifically for GCP messages as `json_format.MessageToJson(entry.payload_pb)` fails on `TypeError: Can not find message descriptor by type_url: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog.`

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to convert the `Any` directly to JSON, rather than a message deserialized from `Any.value`.  I added a note about registering the descriptor that might help.